# How to display dropdown list with long option value on mobile?

Tags: html, css, mobile, twitter-bootstrap-3, html-select

I'm using the following code on both mobile and desktop browser with Bootstrap framework:

```
<select style="font-size:12px">
    <option value="A">A. This is long description for option selection A</option>
    <option value="B">B. This is long description for option selection B</option>
    <option value="C">C. This is long description for option selection C</option>
    <option value="D">D. This is long description for option selection D</option>
    <option value="E">E. This is long description for option selection E</option>
</select>
```

This is not an issue for desktop browser, I can use the `font-size` to make it bigger or smaller.

But when viewing on mobile, especially in portrait mode, I would like the user to see the entire full description of each option.

The default mobile browser dropdown selection is clipping the long description to fit current screen width of the device.

Is there a solution to it?

What's the best approach to present a dropdown list with long option value on mobile devices?

Comment: I have also faced this issue and hope this link will help you. https://select2.github.io/examples.html

Comment: Works perfect for my situation.  I would be glad to accept it as a working solution if you submit it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use Select2 Jquery plugin for responsive dropdown list. This could help you.
https://select2.github.io/examples.html